# How to upload extra images to magento listing using Magmi media_gellery?

Tags: magento, gallery, media, magmi

I am trying to upload listing to magento using Magmi. All works fine except adding extra images with media_gallery. I am using images from remote server and separating hrefs with semicolons as in example in docs. but still having problems. 
Peace from csv:

```
  ..,media_gallery,...
 ..,http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/n4YAAOSw5dNWoA55/$_57.JPG,http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTQ3M1g5ODI/z/lFwAAOSwkZhWTOOF/$_57.JPG;http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTQ3M1g5ODI/z/vX4AAOSwZVhWTOOC/$_57.JPG,..
```

Am I doing something wrong with this column?

Comment: Try with semicolon ; as separator instead of comma

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was image name, because it is same it gets overwritten. You have to make sure that images in media_gallery has different names. In this case renaming functionality in configuration would not help, as it will rename all images to same name again.